# Data duplication issue in SQL/BI

Tags: mysql, sql, looker

I am having a data "fanout" issue with billing data. Specifically it is like this. Suppose you are a customer and pay an invoice. However a payment can apply to multiple invoices so if I make a payment of $100 for invoice X, Y and Z when I sum these up it will become $300.

This is because an invoice can have multiple payments associated to it. So when I want to look at the sum of payments compared to invoices it creates a fanout for invoice amountss.

What is a strategy to solve this?

```
+-----------+
|  INVOICE  |
+-----------+
| ID        |
| AMOUNT    |
| BALANCE   |
| PAYMENTID |
+-----------+
```

and

```
+---------+
| PAYMENT |
+---------+
| ID      |
| AMOUNT  |
+---------+
```

If the goal here is to have a sum of both payments and invoice amounts

Comment: Fanout is jargon can you rephrase. Also do payments just go into a bucket(more jargon) and invoices get paid from there, How do you know when invoice and payment events occur.

Comment: Payment Effective Date and Invoice Date.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you've got something like this (BigQuery syntax):

```
view: invoice {
  derived_table: {
    sql: SELECT *
      FROM UNNEST(ARRAY<STRUCT<ID STRING, COST FLOAT64, PAYMENTID STRING>>[
('X', 10, '1'),
('Y', 30, '1'),
('Z', 60, '1')])
;;
  }
  dimension: id {
    type: string
    primary_key: yes
  }
  dimension: cost {
    type: number
  }
  dimension: paymentid {
    type: string
  }
  measure: total_cost {
    type: sum
    sql: ${cost} ;;
  }
  measure: total_amount {
    type: sum
    sql: ${payment.amount} ;;
  }
}

view: payment {
  derived_table: {
    sql: SELECT *
      FROM UNNEST(ARRAY<STRUCT<PAYMENTID STRING, AMOUNT FLOAT64>>[
('1', 100), 
('2', 200)])
;;
  }
  dimension: paymentid {
    primary_key: yes
    type: string
  }
  dimension: amount {
    type: number
  }
}

explore: invoice {
  join: payment {
    sql_on: ${invoice.paymentid} = ${payment.paymentid} ;;
  }
}
```

This does indeed show total invoice as being the sum of the invoices because you're denormalising the table by joining first.

[image: Three rows of invoice data for X, Y, Z, showing total 100 per row, and total 300 for the table]

If you create the total measure in the view it belongs to, Looker's symmetric aggregates will take care of the fanning using the primary keys.

```
view: invoice {
  derived_table: {
    sql: SELECT *
      FROM UNNEST(ARRAY<STRUCT<ID STRING, COST FLOAT64, PAYMENTID STRING>>[
('X', 10, '1'),
('Y', 30, '1'),
('Z', 60, '1')])
;;
  }
  dimension: id {
    type: string
    primary_key: yes
  }
  dimension: cost {
    type: number
  }
  dimension: paymentid {
    type: string
  }
  measure: total_cost {
    type: sum
    sql: ${cost} ;;
  }
}

view: payment {
  derived_table: {
    sql: SELECT *
      FROM UNNEST(ARRAY<STRUCT<PAYMENTID STRING, AMOUNT FLOAT64>>[
('1', 100), 
('2', 200)])
;;
  }
  dimension: paymentid {
    primary_key: yes
    type: string
  }
  dimension: amount {
    type: number
  }
  measure: total_amount {
    type: sum
    sql: ${amount} ;;
  }
}

explore: invoice {
  join: payment {
    sql_on: ${invoice.paymentid} = ${payment.paymentid} ;;
  }
}
```

The totals will then be correct.

[image: Three rows of invoice data for X, Y, Z, showing total 100 per row, and total 100 for the table]

And the total cost equals the total amount.

[image: One rows of invoice data for payment 1, showing total 100 for costs, and total 100 for payment amounts]